# Spring JdbcTemplate is extremely slow when call SQLserver Stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm using JdbcTemplate.execute() to call a SP connected with SQLServer database.
With the same parameters, when I execute the SP directly in SQL Server Management Studio it finishes within 1s, but when I use JdbcTemplate in java it execute over minutes with causes severe performance issue.

Note the stored procedure contains "SET ANSI_NULLS ON" and  "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I finally find that the issue lies on blank values judgement in my SP:

I have some default parameters for the SP and set them as @A nvarchar(255)='', then during the logic I need to use them as logic condition: if(@A is not null and rtrim(ltrim(@A)) <>'')
Just that simple and it works totally good in the Management Studio.

After change that init to @A nvarchar(255) and use if(@A is not null), it also returns the results in JdbcTemplate... so there should be some inner logic for JdbcTemplate to do that empty check but I'm not sure why and how.